# Web Scraping problem with unwanted columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I am a novice and I scrape data on a video game site for an exercise, and, despite my code I do not know where I am wrong, or why I have this result

```
  import requests
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  import pandas as pd

  url = "https://www.senscritique.com/top/resultats/Les_meilleurs_jeux_video_Ubisoft/798015"
  response = requests.get(url)

  if response.ok:
     links = []
     soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
     for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': 'elco-anchor'}):
         link=link.get('href')
         links.append('https://www.senscritique.com'+ link)
     print(links)

  with open('test.txt', 'w') as file:
       for link in links : 
           file.write(link + '\n')

 url = 'https://www.senscritique.com/jeuvideo/Assassin_s_Creed_II/116618'
 response = requests.get(url)
 if response.ok :
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    test = soup.select('b',attrs={'class': 'pvi-stats-number '})

    name = soup.find('h1',  attrs={'class': 'pvi-product-title' }).text.strip()

    note_redac = soup.find('span',attrs={'class': 'pvi-scrating-value'})
    nb_critique = test[0]
    coup_de_coeur=test[1]
    envie_de_jouer= test[2]
    joueur_ponctuelle = test[3]
```

It is for this part of the code that my result does not correspond to my expectations

```
 with open('urls.txt', 'r') as inf:
      with open ('ubisoft1.csv','w', encoding= 'utf8' )as f:
           f.write('Name, Note, Critique, Coup_de_coeur, Envie,Joueur')
           for row in inf:
               url =  row.strip()
               response = requests.get(url)
               if response.ok :
                  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
                  title = soup.find('h1',  attrs={'class': 'pvi-product-title' 
                                                   }).text.strip()
                  note_redac = soup.find('span',attrs={'class': 'pvi-scrating- 
                                                       value'}).text.strip()
                  nb_critique = soup.select('b',attrs={'class': 'pvi-stats-number '}) 
                                                                     [0].text.strip()
                  coup_de_coeur = soup.select('b',attrs={'class': 'pvi-stats-number '}) 
                                                                     [1].text.strip()
                  envie_de_jouer = soup.select('b',attrs={'class': 'pvi-stats-number '}) 
                                                                     [2].text.strip()
                  joueur_ponctuelle = soup.select('b',attrs={'class': 'pvi-stats-number '}) 
                                                                     [3].text.strip()
                  f.write(str(title) + ',' + str(note_redac) +',' +str(nb_critique) + ',' + 
                  str(coup_de_coeur) + ',' + str(envie_de_jouer) + ','+ 
                  str(joueur_ponctuelle)+ '\n' )
   df = pd.read_csv('ubisoft1.csv', sep = ',')
   df.head()
```

when I call my file 'ubisoft 1.csv', additional columns appear: ['Assassins Creed'], ['7.6'] ...
do you have an idea please?

Comment: What is inside `urls.txt`? You should use `csv` module or `pandas` to create `csv` file

Comment: i use csv module

Comment: You're creating `ubisoft1.csv` directly with `f.write`

Comment: In urls.txt  there is "with open('urls.txt', 'w') as file:
                                       for link in links : 
                                              file.write(link + '\n')